# VBA to Export CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I found this code that was very helpful, but I need a slight modification to make sure that it is saving copies with new names instead of overwriting. Is there anyway for it to automatically input the date as part of the file name?

```
Sub ExportAsCSV()

Dim MyFileName As String
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, InStrRev(CurrentWB.Name, ".") - 1) & ".csv"
'Optionally, comment previous line and uncomment next one to save as the current sheet name
'MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & CurrentWB.ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv"


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course there is - modify the code that creates `MyFileName` to include the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA `Now` will not work because Windows API has file name conventions, which will prevent these characters:

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

So wee need to adjust the Date format. `Now` returns like this:

```
9/29/2020 12:45:26 PM
```

We can adjust like this:

```
9-29-2020
```

Then use the `Format()` function:

```
MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, InStrRev(CurrentWB.Name, ".") - 1) & Format(Now,"mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv"
```

[VBA Format() - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but does this work?

```
MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, InStrRev(CurrentWB.Name, ".") - 1) & Now & ".csv"
```